# Why the text extracted from PDF using PDF text extractors for java such as PDFBox , itext are scatted and unstructured?

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I extracted text from a pdf using both Apache PDFbox and iText. But both the extracted text are completely unstructured and messy

This is

[image]

but the extracted text is ::

> 111111 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
>   
>  US008631488B2 
>  (12) United States Patent (10) Patent No.: US
>   8,631,488 B2 
>  Oz et al. 
>   (45) Date of Patent: Jan. 14,2014
>   
>  6,813,682 B2 1112004 Bress et al. 
>  (54) SYSTEMS AND METHODS
>   FOR PROVIDING 
>  7,065,644 B2 Daniell et al. 
>  6/2006 
>   SECURITY SERVICES DURING POWER 
>  Todd et al. 
>  7,076,690 Bl
>   7/2006 
>  MANAGEMENT MODE 
>  7,086,089 B2 8/2006 Hrastar et al.
>   
>  7,184,554 B2 2/2007 Freese 
>  (75) Inventors: Ami Oz, Azur
>   (IL); Shlomo Touboul, 
>  7,283,542 B2 
>  10/2007 Mitchell 
>   7,353,533 B2 Wright et al. 
>  Kefar Haim (IL) 4/2008 
>  Maufer et
>   al.
>  7,359,983 Bl 4/2008
>  7,360,242 B2 4/2008 Syvanne
>  (73)
>   Assignee: CUPP Computing AS, Bergen (NO)
>  7,418,253 B2 8/2008
>   Kavanagh
>  (Continued)
>  Notice: Subject to any disclaimer, the
>   term of this
>  ( * )
>  patent is extended or adjusted under 35
>   FOREIGN PATENT DOCUMENTS
>  U.S.c. 154(b) by 656 days. wo 2000078008
>   12/2000
>  Appl. No.: 12/535,650
>  (21)
>  WO 2004030308
>   4/2004
>  (22) Filed: Aug. 4, 2009
>  OTHER PUBLICATIONS
>  Breeden
>   H, John et al., "A Hardware FirewallYou TakeWithYou,"
>  (65) Prior
>   Publication Data
>  Government Computer News, located at
>   http:/gcn.com!Articles/
>  US 2010/0037321 Al Feb. 11,2010
>   2005/06/0 11A-hardware-firewall-you-take-with-you.aspx?p~1, Jun.
>   1,2005.

Why this happening ? How to solve this ?

Comment: As you neither provide the PDF in question nor your extraction code calling PDFBox and iText, how can anyone tell why that is happening, let alone how to solve it? That being said, comparing with your image the text looks like a proper top to bottom, left-to-right, text-only text extraction result.

Comment: Since you are attempting to "extract" a 2-column, heavily formatted text, about the only improvement possible would be to recognize the two columns as such. Their widths probably need to be hardcoded for anything useful. What sort of output were you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

The PDF format is designed to allow a document to be displayed and printed correctly, not to allow structured access to the text content. Extracting text from a PDF document is similar to running the printed page through an OCR software. You may not have to recognize the glyphs and convert them to characters, but the structure and logical text flow of the document must be estimated.

If you don't use the naive text extraction examples, both iText and PDFBox (if I remember correctly) give you much more detailed access to the document elements. In this case you would both need the text content as well as the position on the page to be able to reconstruct the content in a meaningful way.

Comment: *if I remember correctly* - Yes, both PDFBox and iText provide parser frameworks which forward more detailed information on parsed text operations, not merely the text but also position and formatting.

Answer (score 0):

A good PDF structure plain text reprex should look like this:-

[image]

Note that the text is defined from the left and whitespace has been replaced by spacebar symbols so needs to be shown using a proportional font. However it will still look like random lines, when the two column output is approximated. To avoid that you need to use clip boundaries (1 for each column.) There are tools and libraries that can fare much better by using the real X Y offsets for each piece of text, but then you need a structured reader like a Word Processor to place the text at those co-ordinates.