# Is it possible to regex search text in a PDF or Word document using java?

Tags: java, regex, pdf, itext, pdfbox

I am not asking any products recommendations

I want to search text from a word document or pdf document using a regular expression with Java. Is it possible? How to do this?

For example, the `PDF/DOC` look like this:

```
(54) About Keyboard                                     More Info

Date: 29/02/2003                                     Printed: US
Filed: 19/03/2005                                     Viewed: 5 times
```

Now my aim is to run a regex-based search on this document using java.

Initially, I tried text extraction but since these are unstructured and scattered I can't use the extracted text.

For example, I want to do this:

```
File fl = new File ("sample.pdf");
String res=  FindBYRegex ("(?s)\\(54\\)\\s*(.*?)\\s*(?=\\(\\d|$\\))");
System.out.println (res);
```

The output I want would be: `(54) About Keyboard`

How to achieve my objective? Which library help me to do this using Java?

Comment: Concerning PDFs: You can apply text search (by regular expression or otherwise) only to the *text* you can somehow extract from the PDF; thus, half your task is [text extraction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21138731/why-the-text-extracted-from-pdf-using-pdf-text-extractors-for-java-such-as-pdfbo) the text from which you say you *can't use*.

Answer (score 1):

Directly you cannot search using Java. You can use [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) to extract the contents of the file then you can apply the Regular Expression.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to search text from a word document or pdf document using Regular Expression from Java . IS it possible ? How to do this ?

Gnostice PDFOne for Java supports searching text in PDF documents using Java Regular Expression. For more details, follow the link below.

http://www.gnostice.com/nl_article.asp?id=232&t=PDF_Text_Search_And_PDF_Text_Extraction_Using_PDFOne_for_Java

Disclaimer: I work for Gnostice.